# How to encrypt payload in Python to make a payment - Adyen payment gateway

Tags: python, encryption, adyen

I'm fairly new to coding, this is one of my first bigger Python projects that I'm working on and I have a problem with Adyen payment submission.

I'm trying to make a payment on a website that uses an Adyen payment gateway. Adyen encrypts your payment data client side and only accepts encrypted requests otherwise they'll throw back a 400 bad request and the payment will not go through.

I'm stuck when it comes to ideas, I analyzed the traffic in Charles when I'm making a payment manually - before making a payment the phone will send a GET request to [this](https://live.adyen.com/hpp/cse/js/1214343660265799.shtml) link on the Adyen website and then the next request is a PUT request to the payment URL with the data already encrypted.

I have no idea how I can encrypt my details in a way that Adyen will accept them and the payment goes through successfully.
Do I make a JS file on my computer with the code from the link before making a payment and then I can just call the JS in my Python script to encrypt the details?

I've tried sending unencrypted data to the payment URL but like I previously said it just throws back a 400 status code and the payment doesn't go through.
The encrypted data that a correct request sends looks something like this:
`"encryptedData": "adyenjs_0_1_18$......"`

```
def payment():
        payParams = {
            'api_key': 'websiteAPIKey',
            'channel': 'iphone-mosaic',
            'type': 'CARD'
        }
        payPayload = {
            'number': cardN,
            'expiryMonth': expM,
            'expiryYear': expY,
            'cvc': cvc,
            'holderName': fName + ' ' + lName
        }
        pay = s.put('websiteUsingAdyenGateway', headers = payHeaders, params = payParams, data = json.dumps(payPayload))
```

The expected result should be a 200 status code with the payment actually going through but with no encryption, it always throws back a 400 status code.

Comment: Have you read official docs ?
https://docs.adyen.com/classic-integration/cse-integration-ecommerce/
The encryption process example is described there. Is it missing something you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are inserting yourself into the processes where you shouldn't. Adyen is ***purposefully*** encrypting the details for you on the client. This is required for [PCI compliancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).

**Only handle [raw card data](https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/api-integration/collecting-raw-card-data/) if you are PCI level 1 or 2**. You need to be processing one million or more transactions annually to qualify.

Presuming not, you should be using a component (Adyen term for a bundled js shopper collection form) to collect the card details. You have two components to choose from:

- [card component](https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/api-integration/#step-2-collect-shopper-details): more plug-and-play, insert a single div for all card collection fields
- [secure fields component](https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/api-integration/build-your-own-payment-form/#step-2-collect-shopper-details-with-secured-fields): more customizable, insert a div for each fields of a card (e.g. number, cvc, expiration)

> Note: Both require you to [create an origin key](https://docs.adyen.com/user-management/how-to-get-an-origin-key/) that has to match to the domain you are making a payment. e.g. if you are doing a test and hosting your server on localhost on port 8080, create an origin key for `http://localhost:8080`.

In either case, both of these require you to implement a callback that will provide you the encrypted blobs you need to pass to Adyen.

```js
function handleOnChange(state, component) {
    if (state.isValid){
        // All card fields pass formatting validation
        fetch('localhost:8080/handleComponentData',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(state.data)
        })
    }
}
```

That `state.data` can be passed, as is, in the `paymentMethod` object as part of a [`/payments`](https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/api-integration/#step-3-make-a-payment) request

state.data's contents:

```
{
    type: "scheme",
    encryptedCardNumber: "adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...",
    encryptedExpiryMonth: "adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...",
    encryptedExpiryYear: "adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...",
    encryptedSecurityCode: "adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH..."
}
```

The /payment request:

```sh
curl https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v46/payments \
-H "x-API-key: YOUR_X-API-KEY" \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "amount":{
    "currency":"EUR",
    "value":1000
  },
  "reference":"YOUR_ORDER_NUMBER",
  "paymentMethod":{
    "type":"scheme",
    "encryptedCardNumber":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...",
    "encryptedExpiryMonth":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...",
    "encryptedExpiryYear":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH...",
    "encryptedSecurityCode":"adyenjs_0_1_18$MT6ppy0FAMVMLH..."
  },
  "returnUrl":"https://your-company.com/checkout/",
  "merchantAccount":"YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT"
}'
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to test this on the back end?  I'm trying to find a test data to pass into the "paymentMethod" object.  Is there any test 'encryptedCardNumber'?